# Set `lintr` for sublime text 3: change line length

Tags: r, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I am using `sublimeLinter-contrib-lintr` and `lintr` in sublime text 3 (Sublime Text 3) to lint `R`. One thing I would like to change is the line length flag. At this moment, Sublime Text 3 keeps reminding me that `"lines should not be more than 80 characters"`. I would to change the line length to be 120. [`lintr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lintr/README.html) suggests change the user setting of `sublime linter` by editing the following,

```
{
  "user": {
    "linters": {
      "r": {
        "linters": "with_defaults(line_length_linter(120))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After the above configuration and restarting Sublime Text 3, the system still reports "80 characters" reminder. Could anyone explain this? The computer is running Mac El Capitan. I don't think path is an issue because `sublime linter` can lint the `R` files. The final settings I used is the following

```
"user": {
    "linters": {
        "lintr": {
            "@disable": false,
            "args": [],
            "cache": "TRUE",
            "excludes": [],
            "linters": "with_defaults(line_length_linter = line_length_linter(120))"
        }
    }
}
```

I also notice that in the user setting of `sublime linter`, there is no `"r":{...}` but `"lintr":{...}`. I assume that in terms of settings, `lintr` is just `r`.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please tell me briefly how did you get the `lintr` to work in `Sublime`? I've added the path, but it still don't lint. Thanks.

Comment: @F.Gran I have abandoned `lintr` long time ago. I think I just follow the [instructions](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-contrib-lintr) of the `lintr` package of ST3.